# $compile a directive from bootstrap-ui in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, accordion, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I think I have a problem with dependency injection but I'm a bit lost.

In my controller I'm getting some data from a server and putting it in a $scope variable. 
In my directive I have a link that contains a watcher on the $scope variable and the callback creates the charts and tables. This works fine where I only want to display the charts. The problem I have is when I want to code-generate a variable amount of tables(based on the content of the data received) and encapsule them in an accordion from bootstrap-ui. This means I have to call $compile at the end of my link. As long as I code-generated some scope content ({{ var }} ) or a standard angular directive (ng-repeat), it's works but when I try putting an accordion directive and compile it, I get those errors:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$compile/ctreq?p0=accordionGroup&p1=accordionTransclude
        at Error (native)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:6:450
        at L (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:51:216)
        at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:54:244)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:135)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:152)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:152)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:152)
        at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:54:149)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:135) <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading"> angular.js:10023
        2014-08-21 16:36:51.433
        Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cdivlass%3D%22panel-body%22%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%3E
        at Error (native)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:6:450
        at xa.link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:203:112)
        at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:54:208)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:135)
        at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:54:149)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:135)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:152)
        at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:54:149)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:135) angular.js:10023
        2014-08-21 16:36:51.435
        Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cdivlass%3D%22panel-group%20ng-scope%22%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%3E
        at Error (native)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:6:450
        at xa.link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:203:112)
        at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:54:208)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:47:135)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:46:258
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:48:97
        at w (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:51:389)
        at xa.link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:203:129)
        at M (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:54:208)
```

Those errors appear whenever that directive is present in my element (code-added or in the html template)  and I compile the element.

I suppose it has something to do with me not injecting angular-ui but I have no idea how to do it.

I created 2 examples where I find a weird behavior: in the first scenario (without a $watch) it compiles without any errors but the content is not displayed. In the second one (with a $watch) it gives the same errors I had (I suppose it's some problem with the scope of the callback but I'm a bit lost)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

http://plnkr.co/edit/2vXc6KMZgk5rEkLVOQFA?p=preview

http://plnkr.co/edit/7z5V9k4F1uT4HQJPcr01?p=preview

The examples look like this:

```
angular.module('docsBindExample', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
  setTimeout(function(){ $scope.loop = true; $scope.$apply();}, 2000);

}])
.directive('test', ['$compile',  function($compile) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link
  };

  function link($scope, $elem, $attr)
  {
    $scope.$watch('loop', function ()
    {
      if ($scope.loop)
      {
        console.log($scope.loop);
        $scope.loop = false;
        $elem = $compile($elem)($scope);
      }
    });
  }

}]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to compile after the variable changes, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? It seems to work as it should with this removed.

Comment: Without the compile the <accordion> isn't converted to actual code (in my example I'm not changing the content of the element in the code but if I want to do add directives they have to be compiled).
This is just an example to show that there is a problem (if you remove the <accordion> tags the code does what it should do (execute the repeat on the element which is composed of the 3 already repeated messages).

Answer (score 0):

You could just target the element you want to compile.

```
        var div = $elem.children()[1]
        $elem = $compile(div)($scope);
```

[**Modified Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HcLKJk3QJt5rfrbQgiEV?p=preview)